# How to automatically process queued job in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I know `dispatch()` will push the job the queue, and `php artisan queue:work` will process it.
Say If I am sending a mail.

```
   $emailJob = (new SendEmailJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
   dispatch($emailJob);
   echo "email sent";
```

What this code means? Will send the mail after 3 seconds or Will it push the job to queue after 3 second?

If it will push the job the queue, how will I send it.
I certainly can't do `php artisan queue:work` while the project is deployed.

Suppose I have to send mails to 1000 members. 
What I will do I will push all the jobs to the queue and let it process in the background without affecting the other process. Like if other requests are coming. It should handle it without any delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs works in a way that you have a queue worker (the `php artisan queue:work` command) that wait jobs to process and then executes them at the scheduled time.

So you have to keep that running in background in your developement environment to let it catch the incoming jobs and let it process when the right time comes.

While you have your queue processor in background, you can trigger your code that pushes the job into the queue.
The first line will schedule the job to be run after three seconds, so the delay is for the execution time, not the queuing time.
Then the `dispatch` function is an helper to actually push the job on the queue.

After you pushed your job, the queue processor will notice it and will see that it has been scheduled with a delay of 3 seconds, so it will process it only when the right schedule time comes.

#### Supervisor

In production, you have to keep a background process that execute `php artisan queue:work` for your queue to be processed. That is explained as well on Laravel's documentation about Queues [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#supervisor-configuration).

They use supervisor to always have N instances of the `php artisan queue:work` running in parallel and if any of these fails, it gets restarted automatically, so your queue will be processed correctly

Comment: what `dispatch()` does actually? I tested but it doesn't send the mail after 3 seconds? I used `queue:work`. Then It sent.

Comment: The `dispatch()` places the item in a queue and `queue:work` will go through all items in the queue. The item you dispatched to the queue will not be processed until the 3 seconds have elapsed.

Comment: I explained more in detail my answer. You actually have to keep `queue:work` running in background, then whenever a job gets pushed in the  queue, your worker will notice and run in at the scheduled time